# migrate SharePoint to SBS Server

Tags: sharepoint-2007, windows-sbs-2011, migration

We have a SharePoint 2003 server and we need to migrate that data to SharePoint 2011 on a SBS server.  We cannot use the migration tool because one of the servers is SBS and the other is not.

We exported the SharePoint data from the old system, but the import to the SBS SharePoint is failing with very little info on why.  I think that there is a schema conflict, but I am not that familiar with SBS and I am not finding the error in the Windows logs.

Has anyone had to migrate data from non-SBS system to an SBS system?  Or can anyone help me figure out where to look for more info on what is going on?

Comment: Maybe useful: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12483/migrating-from-sharepoint-2003-to-2010

Answer (score 0):

I know one migration tool that could help you complete your migration scenario Non-SBS SP2003 to SBS SP2010 (Windows SBS 2011 works with SP2010) it is Sharegate!

You could have migrated directly from the source server but since you already have the data exported, you still can import this data using the Export to SharePoint tool.

I invite you to take a look at Sharegate: http://en.share-gate.com/ there is a free 15-day trial that would allow you to see for yourself.

Please contact me at support@share-gate.com for more information or if you have any questions.

Jimmy De Santis
Sharegate User experience Guardian